# Убрать символ перевода строки из регулярки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно убрать символ перевода строки из регулярки, чтоб его не резал. Никакой таблицы символов не нашёл, может кто знает за каким кодом он стоит?

```
preg_replace('/([^\pL\pN\pP\pS\pZ])|([\xC2\xA0])/u', ' ', $string);
```

Вся функция:

```
function istrip($string) {
  $old_string = $string;
  $string = strip_tags($string);
  $string = preg_replace('/([^\pL\pN\pP\pS\pZ])|([\xC2\xA0])/u', ' ', $string);
  $string = str_replace('  ',' ', $string);
  $string = trim($string);

  if ($string === $old_string) {
    return $string;
  } else {
    return istrip($string); 
  }  
}
```

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/8aaQoQ/1)

Comment: \pZ - дока http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category

Comment: @Jean-Claude так же в 1 строку всё, поправил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы не резало, нужно не убрать, а добавить символ `\pC`(соединяющая пунктуация) :

```
preg_replace('/([^\pL\pN\pP\pS\pZ\pC])|([\xC2\xA0])/u', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: Работает, но выводит непечатаемые символы как знак вопроса

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/[\x00\x80-\xFF]/', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: Не работает с русскими символами, кому надо, возьмёт, оставлю тут.